# Query Activerecord HABTM relationship to include ALL elements of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Forum` and `ForumTag` HABTM relationship. I also have an array of variables named `@tags` . This array contains the names of some ForumTags. I want to be able to query and find all forums that have ALL the values of the array. I currently have:

> @forums = Forum.joines(:forum_tags).where(:forum_tags => {:name => @tags}).includes(:forum_tags).all

However, this returns all the forums that have AT LEAST ONE value in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will require the forums to have all the forum tags in the `@tags` array.  I am making the assumption that a `forum` will not have the same `forum_tag` more than once.

```
@forums = Forum.joins(:forum_tags).where(:forum_tags => {:name => @tags}).group("forums.id").having(['COUNT(*) = ?', @tags.length]).includes(:forum_tags).all
```

This will produce an SQL query like the following:

```
@tags = ['foo', 'bar']

SELECT forums.id, forum_tags.id FROM forums
  LEFT OUTER JOIN forum_tags_forums on forum_tags_forums.forum_id = forums.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN forum_tags ON forum_tags.id = forum_tags_forums.forum_tag_id
  WHERE forum_tags.name IN ('foo', 'bar')
  GROUP BY forums.id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

This will group all the rows in the join table by forums that match the given tags.  If the `COUNT` function has the value of the total number of tags that you're looking for (and there are no duplicate `forum`/`forum_tag` pairs) then the forum must contain all the tags.

To get the leftover tags (question asked in the comments):

```
forum_tags = ForumTag.where(:name => @tags)

@forums_with_leftovers = Forum.select("forums.*, GROUP_CONCAT(forum_tags.name) AS leftover_tags").joins(:forum_tags).where(['forums.id IN (?) AND NOT forum_tags.id IN (?)', @forums, forum_tags]).group("forums.id").all
```

Each `Forum` object in `@forums_with_leftovers` will have an extra attribute `leftover_tags` that contains a comma separated list of tags in each forum object that is not in the original `@tags` variable.

Comment: Works like a charm. Follow-up: if I wanted to then set a leftover_tags variable to all the leftover tags that are included in the query. For example, if there is a forum tagged with ['foo','bar','blah'] and the tags array only has ['foo', 'bar'].... I would want leftover_tags to be ['blah']

Comment: I've updated the answer with a subsequent query for the leftover tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
@forums = Forum.joins(:forum_tags).where(:forum_tags => {:name => @tags}).group("forums.id").having(['COUNT(*) = ?', @tags.length]).includes(:forum_tags).all
```

This solution propoused by Don Cruickshank was briliant! It worked perfectly for me. However, there is no need for the last .includes and .all.