# Rails query based on HABTM match

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to query a Conversation based on the users that are in the HABTM relationship. I have `conversations`, `users`, and `conversations_users` tables and need to grab the conversations based on the users that are in the conversation.

The `Conversation` model contains a HABTM relationship to `:users`.

I have tried this:

`Conversation.includes(:users).where(users: {id: [8,10]})`

but it uses an OR statement and I need both 8 AND 10 to be be required

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question and I can't see your models to make sure it's correct, but you should be able to say Conversation.users to get a list of it's users that belong to a given conversation.  Does that not work, or produce and error?

Comment: I could query each conversation and then query for each user and check against the users that I need, but that seems why too intensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems that the following will do what I need:

```
user_ids = [8,10]

Conversation.joins(:users)
.where(users: {id: user_ids})
.group("conversations.id")
.having(['COUNT(*) = ?', user_ids.count])
```

refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9449300/1476099) answer for more details